# Make W3 School Draggable DIV Element mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, draggable

Does somebody know how to convert the W3 School draggable div example to work on mobile devices? I am new to javascript so I do not know how do achieve this Please help!

(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that `touchstart` is equivalent to `mousedown` and `touchmove` to `mousemove` and `touchend` to `mouseup`. I'd be wrong though for this example. But why not use a 3rd party library which will handle all the stuff for you so you won't have to re-invent it.

```js
// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    modifiers: [
      interact.modifiers.restrictRect({
        restriction: 'parent',
        endOnly: true
      })
    ],
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,

    listeners: {
      // call this function on every dragmove event
      move: dragMoveListener,

      // call this function on every dragend event
      end(event) {
        var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p')

        textEl && (textEl.textContent =
          'moved a distance of ' +
          (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageX - event.x0, 2) +
            Math.pow(event.pageY - event.y0, 2) | 0))
          .toFixed(2) + 'px')
      }
    }
  })

function dragMoveListener(event) {
  var target = event.target
  // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
  var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
  var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

  // translate the element
  target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

  // update the posiion attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
}

// this function is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener
```

```css
#drag-1,
#drag-2 {
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 6.5em;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  padding: 4%;
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>

<div id="drag-1" class="draggable">
  <p> You can drag one element </p>
</div>
<div id="drag-2" class="draggable">
  <p> with each pointer </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Courtesy of [interactjs](https://interactjs.io/) example